# Como pasar datos de props a un state en React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

El dato es enviando desde un componente hijo a un componente padre utilizando React Hooks y Redux, el dato llega correctamente al componente padre y lo puedo visualizar inicialmente con un console.log pero necesito pasar ese dato a un estado ya iniciado, ya que ese estado se pasa a un input en el cual me muestra los datos y lo puedo editar.
El problema esta que no puedo pasar el dato del props directamente al estado ya que me genera un renderizado infinito, y cuando intento pasar el dato directamente al input, no lo toma como un cambio y no lo deja editar ya que el dato no es el estado inicial.

Lo ideal seria pasar el dato al estado y el automáticamente lo tomaría como un cambio pero si alguien tiene alguna idea de como resolver este problema seria de mucha ayuda.

Componente hijo

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { Container,Row,Col,Button,Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import {color} from './propStatus' 
import findHistory from '../../redux/actions/findHistory'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const moment = require('moment');

const History = (props) => {
    const tableData = props.tableData      
    const dataHistory= (e,data) => {
        e.preventDefault();             
        props.addHistory({jsonHistory:data.jsonHistory,statusHistory:data.statusHistory,responseHistory:data.responseHistory})                            
    }

    return(        
        tableData.sort((a, b) => moment(a.date).format('LLL') < moment(b.date).format('LLL') ? 1:-1).map((val,index) =>                                                                                  
            <Container key={index}>                                                           
                <Form onSubmit={(e,dataSubmit) => dataHistory(e,dataSubmit={jsonHistory: val.json,statusHistory: val.state,responseHistory: val.response})}>
                    <p style={{ textAlign:'initial' }}>{ moment(val.date).format('LLL') }</p>   
                    <Row>                                                                                       
                        <Col md={8}>                                                                                      
                            <h6 className='large-text'>{ val.response === '""' ? 'No hay informacion' : val.response }</h6>
                            <h6 className='large-text'>{ val.json }</h6>
                        </Col>                                      
                        <Col md={4}>                                              
                            <Button 
                                variant={color(val.state)}                                   
                                type="submit">
                                { val.state }
                            </Button>                                                                                                                           
                        </Col>                                       
                    </Row>                                                                                                                                                 
                    <hr/>                                                                                    
                </Form>
            </Container>    
        )
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>({    
    addHistory:data=>dispatch(findHistory(data))
})

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(History);
```

Componente padre

```
import React, { useState,useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Container,Row,Col,Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ContentHistoryState from '../components/ThirdParty/ContentHistoryState'
import EmptyHistoryState from '../components/ThirdParty/EmptyHistoryState'
import '../components/css/blog.css'
import Paginate from '../components/Paginate'
const moment = require('moment');
let day = moment();

function Home(props) {
    const code = props.sendCode  
    const title = props.sendTitle  
    const history = props.history
    const [resp, setRespList] = useState([])       
    const [historyList, setHistoryList] = useState([])  

    const [json, setJson] = useState('') 
    const [state, setState] = useState('') 
    const [response] = useState('')  
    let hJson = 0
    try{
        if(history[0].history){
            hJson = history[0].history.jsonHistory
            console.log(history[0].history.statusHistory)            
        }
    }catch(e){    
    }

    const handleCount = useCallback(() => {
        console.log(state)
        setState(history[0].history.statusHistory)
        console.log(state)
    },[]);    
    

    useEffect(() => {       
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3000/get/history',{
            code: code,
            client:1
        })
        .then(response => response)
        .then((data) => {            
            const countKey = Object.keys(data.data).length;            
            let info= []
            for(let i=0;i< countKey; i++){                
                info.push(data.data[i])                  
            }               
            setHistoryList(info)  
        }) 
    },[])
    
    const submit = (data) => {         
        const jsonSend = data.json 
        setState('') 
        if(resp.length !== 0 )   
            resp.shift() 

        Axios.post("http://localhost:3000/set/thirdParty",{
            json: jsonSend,
            code: code,            
        })
        .then(response =>response) 
        .then(data =>{                           
            setRespList([
                ...resp,                              
                {
                    status: data.status,
                    statusText: data.statusText,
                    info: data.data,                    
                }
            ]) 
            day = moment().format();
            const j=({'date':day,'json':jsonSend,'response':JSON.stringify(data.data),'state':data.status })
            setHistoryList(j)                                                        
        })
        .catch(error => {              
            setRespList([
                ...resp,                                                                                                                                           
                {       
                    status: error.response.status,
                    statusText: error.response.statusText,
                    info: error.toString(),                    
                }
            ])                                                                      
        })         
    }
    const handleChange= (data) => {
        console.log(data)    
        setJson(data)                            
        //hJson = data
    }

    const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
    () => {
        setJson(hJson)
    },
    [hJson],
    );

    

    return(        
        <div className='home mt-3'>       
            <Container fluid> 
                <h5>{ title } </h5>       
                <hr/>
                <Row>                                                              
                    <Col md={5}>                                      
                        { historyList.length !== 0
                            ? <Paginate historyList={ historyList }/>
                            : <h6>Load...</h6>
                        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={7}>
                        <label>Ingresa la informaci&oacute;n</label>                        
                        <textarea
                            rows="8"
                            type="text"
                            name="json"
                            className="form-control mb-3"  
                            value={ hJson !== 0 ? memoizedCallback : json }  
                            onChange={(e)=> {
                                handleChange(e.target.value)                                                          
                        }}>                          
                        </textarea>  
                        <Button
                            variant="dark"                           
                            onClick={(dataClick) => 
                            submit(dataClick={json: json})}>
                            Send Data
                        </Button>                         
                        {   state 
                            ?   <ContentHistoryState                                    
                                state={ state }
                                response={ response }/>                                                                                                
                            :   <EmptyHistoryState
                                resp={ resp }/>                          
                        }
                    </Col>  
                </Row>                                                             
            </Container>                                  
        </div>
    )    
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {    
    if(state.history.length > 1)
        state.history.shift();
    
    return {
        history: state.history
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(Home);
```

Comment: Hola, porque haces que el estado que estás modificando con el evento onChange se vuelva a guardar en el value del input ?

Comment: Para que tome los datos como una modificacion, cada que se vuelve a guardar es porque se a realizado un cambio en el input.¿Me hago entender?

Comment: Si pero, necesariamente tienes que volver a mostrar esos cambios en el input ?

Comment: Si, es obligatorio

Comment: ya lo resolviste? acabo de verlo y ha pasado tiempo

Comment: Si, utilice un useRef para luego compararlo con los datos entrantes.

Comment: hola.. y si nos compartes la respuesta para quien busque esta pregunta?